# Is It about Augmented Reality or Camera Preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, augmented-reality, surfaceholder

I jsu have small inquiry, and please dont underestimate it.

I Have a class that implements Render, and another CLass implements Surface.callback.

When I run the class the implements the surface.Callback, I manage to show the camera preview.

And When I run the class the implements the Render, I manage to display the 3D shaps.

Now, I want to display the 3D shapes over the Camera preview.

My Questions is, what should I learn and read to achieve this? Is is about Augmented Reality?

Or I just need to learn more how the camera preview works?

Your answers would be meaningful and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read how to overlay surfaces.

Augmented Reality is about displaying graphics according to what is shown in the camera (usually it detects a marker and displays graphics according to it).